# How does IP logging works?

Tags: logging, ip-address

This question struck to my mind after watching a video about grabbing someone's IP address using the website https://grabify.link ,I did try to log my own IP and it works! I was wondering how it works, If some one could shed some light on its working or provide some resources so that i can understand how it works, it would be great of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This service is basically a redirection service. The client will request the URL provided by the service and they redirect the user to the URL specified. The original request from the client to grabify.link contains information like their IP address, screen resolution, user agent, etc. like any other request. The only difference with any other redirection service is that they will display the information to creator of the redirect instead of discarding it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer buddy, when i researched on your answer i found that this webpage makes use of UA(User Agent) which is the piece of software which tell the webpage i am visiting all the details as u said "information like their IP address, screen resolution, user agent, etc."